# Assign variables current value JS

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have variable that counts scrolling pixels, and I want on click to assign its current value at the time of click to different variable.

```
var scrl = $('body').scrollTop();

$('div').click(function(){
    var position = scrl;
});
```

This works, but only assigns value once. For example if I scroll to 500px it will assign it that value, but if I scroll again and click it, it will still have value of 500px.

Comment: Get the scroll position inside the event handler.

Comment: Thats the expected behaviour. Use `var position = $('body').scrollTop();`

Comment: Do you expect `scrl` to *magically* change its value? JavaScript is all pass by value. `scrl` is assigned the return value of `$('body').scrollTop()` which is a number. Unless you are assigning a new value to `scrl`, its value will not magically change.

Comment: how do you test the value the second time? try to init the position variable oustide of the function like this :::: var position;  $('div').click(function(){
   position = scrl;
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method call just returns a static value. So `$('body').scrollTop()` will just return the current scroll value and saves it into the `scrl` variable.

As you want to get the current value, you just have to call the method each time:

```
// the element doesn't change, so it can be saved in a var
var $body = $('body');

$('div').click(function () {
    var position = $body.scrollTop();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define scrl inside your click function, otherwise it'll only get once

```
$('div').click(function(){
    var scrl = $('body').scrollTop();
    var position = scrl;
});
```